# При добавлении поста, как передать произвольные поля?

Tags: wordpress

В базу данных при помощи функции wp_insert_post добавляется пост с полями , а произвольные поля добавляются при помощи функции update_post_meta, в которой один из аргументов ID  поста. Функция get_ID() не срабатывает, т.к. пост еще не создался и ID у него нет. Как мне добавить произвольные поля? или как мне в функцию update_post_meta передать ID  создаваемого поста?

```
function ab_insert_cars()
{
$post_data = array(
    'post_type' => 'cars',
    'post_title' => 'title_333',
    'post_content' => 'trhnjtrnnr',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    //'year' => '3037',
);
wp_insert_post( $post_data);
update_post_meta('post', /* ID  поста */, 'year', '3037', true);
}
add_action('init', 'ab_insert_cars');
```

Answer (score 2):

Функция `wp_insert_post()` возвращает id созданного поста. А функция `update_post_meta()` имеет 4 параметра, а не 5, из которых нужны 3.

Ваш код должен выглядеть так

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data);
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'year', '3037' );
```

Comment: the_ID()  возвращает false, a get_the_ID() возвращает NULL

Comment: понял, добился возвращения ID, но произвольное поле в базу так и не добавляется....значения 12343213 в базе нет

Comment: Ну вы хоть иногда в документацию заглядывайте https://wp-kama.ru/function/update_post_meta Я удивляюсь, откуда можно взять примеры вызова с 5 параметрами вместо четырёх, из которых в данном случае нужны только три.

Comment: Дополнил ответ примером кода.

Answer (score 0):

С версии 4.4 можно добавить мета-поля прямо при создании новой записи:

```
$post_data = array(
    'post_type' => 'cars',
    'post_title' => 'title_333',
    'post_content' => 'trhnjtrnnr',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'meta_input' => array(
        'year' => '3037',
    ),
);
wp_insert_post( $post_data);
```

[В русской документации](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_insert_post) параметр `meta_input` не упоминается, а [в английской](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) и [на wp-kama](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_insert_post) он есть.